# Error in retrieving metric values from metric definitions of Microsoft Azure REST api

Tags: rest, azure

I am trying to get the metric values of different metric definitions through the REST uri.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resource groupname}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm name}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2016-09-01
```

It only returns me the Percentage CPU metric values while other metric definitions values doesn't show up.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It only returns me the Percentage CPU metric values while other metric definitions values doesn't show up.

As far as I know, [if no filters are specified, the default metric is returned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough#retrieve-metric-values). You can specify metrics' name in filter to make it returns the metrics that you want.

I'm using the following filters, and I can get `Percentage CPU` and `Network In` metrics from response.

```
$filter=(name.value%20eq%20'Percentage%20CPU'%20or%20name.value%20eq%20'Network%20In')%20and%20startTime%20eq%202017-08-19%20and%20endTime%20eq%202017-08-21
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Pranay Das, any updates? are you able to get the metrics now?

Comment: Thank you @Fred Han I can get data from it